# What is the purpose of CreateOrigin in assets pallet?

Tags: assets

In this PR: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12586, the reasoning given is :

> Required for bridges and accepting other asset classes over XCM.

Can someone explain in more detail what this means? Can one use `CreateOrigin` for purposes like only allowing members of a collective to create an asset class? How would one use the `Arg` from `EnsureOriginWithArg`

```rust
type CreateOrigin: EnsureOriginWithArg<
 Self::RuntimeOrigin,
 Self::AssetId,
 Success = Self::AccountId,
>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `EO` requires an implementation of `EnsureOrigin`.

So, you can combine anyone of them.

Check https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-2.0/blob/8ba1ff7894588a540763c1c24fc74c3848b835fa/runtime/common/src/gov_origin.rs#L28-L43.

Example:
`AsEnsureOriginWithArg<EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, Collective, 1, 2>>`

This means if `1/2` of the collective members voted aye, the `try_origin` will succeed.

Comment: Yes I can see that, but what about the generic `Arg` that's on the trait? Can we use it as a check for `AssetId` if yes how? Furthermore, I would like to use the `Contains` implementation of pallet-membership instead to say if try_origin should succeed, this should be possible I hope.

Comment: Just take a look at how Polkadot uses this. Here you go: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/1c99b3c5434e0232f70b58ae93a7b13ebb7f40a1/xcm/xcm-simulator/example/src/parachain.rs#L142-L163